# Separating Development and Deliverables with Git/Github

Tags: git, github

I am looking for some advice on the best way to manage my development worflow. I have been using git locally to track development and have recently uploaded a couple of private projects into Github.

One project is a Wordpress theme. Before using Github I would commit my changes and then use `git archive` to output my deliverable:

```
git archive master --format=zip --prefix=theme/ > theme.v.1.0.0.zip
```

My gitignore is set up so that it doesn't include things like `package.json` or `node_modules`. It strips out everything that is superfluous to running the theme - i.e. my dev files (node, webpack etc)

As I want to use Github to store my development version, when I push my changes to my Github repo, the same behaviour happens - no package.json or node_modules - which is expected but not what I want.

Ideally, I would want 2 "versions" of my theme -

1. Deliverable version - the one I hand off to the client without `webpack` or `node_modules` or any other item relating to build process. The version that just "works". It would be great if I can just pull down the deliverable from github rather than pulling the development version and building. Is it possible to have an archived (zipped) version as well? (I may be asking too much!)
2. Development version - includes package.json (but not everything in node_modules) so that I can recreate the project to work on.

Comment: You might be able to use branches for this.  You would create pull requests to promote from the "develop" branch to the "master" branch.  In the master branch you would delete those files.  If there are no changes to those files, the pull request won't attempt to create the file.

Comment: It's also very possible to have different content in the `.gitignore` file between the two branches.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Thanks for this. Wondering if branches might make the process a bit more convoluted - at least for me. Having had a think about this, perhaps I should be writing a bash script to build my theme rather than relying on `git archive`?

Comment: Is it possible that git is the wrong place to store the deliverable version? Maybe store it in S3 or something. You'll have two "versions" of the theme, but they're in diff locations.